# What is the meaning of 及义?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, idioms

One of Confucius sayings contains the construction 言不及义. It carries the meaning "unable to talk on serious topics", from what a dictionary gave me. However, I was interested in the per-character structure of such meanings, and went to translate these characters individually.

- 言 - yán - speech
- 不 - bù - a universal negation
- 及 - jí - to reach, to catch, to participate, to improve to a certain extent
- 义 - yì - justice, moral, fact, meaning

So, 'speech not reaching meaning' is the best I can get from this breakdown.

Any help on grasping the meaning is highly appreciated.

Comment: speech not reaching meaning --> speech never get to any meaningful topic

Comment: @TangHo Here, 及义 might mean 'to reach meaning'?

Comment: Yes,及义 means 'reach meaning' and 'speech not reach meaning' because it never get to anything meaningful

Comment: These days we would say "Idle chit-chat"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot was pretty good.

言不及义 - A person's talk does not touch/reach the true/real meaning of the subject he wanted to deliver. He either does not have a thorough understanding of the subject or is not able to organize his thought in a logical manner.